# How to fetch only numbers which are not starting with 2 using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have a list of numbers like the following one:

- 200
- 302
- 301
- 201
- 205
- 500

Using regex, how can I fetch only the numbers which don't start with 2?

So the output should looks like :

- 302
- 301
- 500

Comment: `\b[013-9]` or `\b(?!2)\d` or `\b[^\D2]`?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: How are the numbers stored? In an array, on the DOM? As text? Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

There are multiple ways to accomplish this (presented below).

**Note**: I know the patterns only match the first character. Please read the **entire** answer to understand why (and how to match the full number if that's needed).

---

### Code

The **Usage** section uses the first regex from each method (as it's a simple validation on the first character). The second regex from each method allows you to capture the entire number if that's the intention.

#### Method 1 - Regex: Character set

This method takes 39 steps and is 9 (+3) characters long.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zxys4P/1)

```
\b[013-9]
\b[013-9]\d*
```

#### Method 2 - Regex: Negative lookahead

This method takes 63 steps and is 9 (+1) characters long.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zxys4P/2)

```
\b(?!2)\d
\b(?!2)\d*
```

#### Method 3 - Regex: Negated character set

This method takes 39 steps and is 8 (+3) characters long.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zxys4P/3)

```
\b[^\D2]
\b[^\D2]\d*
```

#### Method 4 - JavaScript: startsWith

```
startsWith("2");
```

#### Method 5 - JavaScript: Array element

Assuming `n` is the number converted to a string.

```
n[0] !== "2"
```

#### Method 6 - JavaScript: Math

Assuming `n` is a positive number (we make it positive for the validation).

```
while(n >= 10) {
    n = Math.floor(n/10);
}
if(n !== 2)
```

---

### Usage

```js
var nums = [200,302,301,201,205,500];

console.log("Method 1");
var r = /\b[013-9]/g
nums.forEach(function(s){
  s = s.toString();
  if(s.match(r)) {
    console.log(s);
  }
});

console.log("\nMethod 2");
var r = /\b(?!2)\d/g
nums.forEach(function(s){
  s = s.toString();
  if(s.match(r)) {
    console.log(s);
  }
});

console.log("\nMethod 3");
var r = /\b[^\D2]/g
nums.forEach(function(s){
  s = s.toString();
  if(s.match(r)) {
    console.log(s);
  }
});

console.log("\nMethod 4");
nums.forEach(function(s){
  s = s.toString();
  if(!s.startsWith("2")) {
    console.log(s);
  }
});

console.log("\nMethod 5");
nums.forEach(function(s){
  s = s.toString();
  if(s[0] !== "2") {
    console.log(s);
  }
});

console.log("\nMethod 6");
nums.forEach(function(s){
  var n = Math.abs(s);
  while(n >= 10) {
    n = Math.floor(n/10);
  }
  if(n !== 2) {
    console.log(s);
  }
});
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
200
302
301
201
205
500
```

#### Output

```
302
301
500
```

---

### Explanation

**Note**: All the regular expressions in my answer use `\b` (word boundary) to ensure the start of the number. You can replace this with your needs. If the input is multiline, for example, you may want to use `^` (start of line assertion) with the multiline flag (typically `m`). The below explanations exclude the explanation of the `\b` token (since I've already explained it).

#### Method 1 - Regex: Character set

- `[013-9]` Match a character in the set (0, 1, or a number in the range of 3-9)

#### Method 2 - Regex: Negative lookahead

- `(?!2)\d` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not a 2.

#### Method 3 - Regex: Negated character set

- `[^\D2]` Match any character not in the set (any non-digit or 2). Note that `[^\D2]` is actually a double negative that means *match any digit, excluding 2*

#### Method 4 - JavaScript: startsWith

From [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> str.startsWith(searchString[, position])
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `searchString`
>
> - The characters to be searched for at the start of this string.
>
> `position` *Optional*
>
> - The position in this string at which to begin searching for `searchString`; defaults to 0.
>
> #### Return value
>
> `true` if the given characters are found at the beginning of the
>   string; otherwise, `false`.
>
> ### Description
>
> This method lets you determine whether or not a string begins with
>   another string. This method is case-sensitive.

#### Method 5 - JavaScript: Array element

This method is simply taking the first digit in a number and testing it against the string `2` to see if they match. Anything that returns `false` is returned (does not start with `2`).

#### Method 6 - JavaScript: Math

This method gets the absolute value of a number [`Math.abs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/math-abs-function-javascript) and then continuously divides the number by 10 while removing decimal places ([`Math.floor(n/10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)) until the number is less than 10. The result is then checked against the number `2` to ensure it doesn't match `if(n !== 2)`.

Comment: Thanks really so much for all the details!

Comment: @LuigiT. you're very welcome! If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask. I know I wrote a huge answer, but I tried to cover all angles of *numbers* and how to determine what the first number is/checking whether or not it's equal to something.